# Blazor <InputSelect> inside <EditForm>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-editform

I tried everything, Googled a lot, still can't get it to work. I'm trying to use `<EditForm>` with `<InputSelect>` to update an existing object(`video` in my case).

1. I want an `InputSelect` with `@bind-Value="video.DisplayId"`. Then the first selected option will be; either 1. `if video.DisplayId is null`, then display `"None"`. 2. `if video.DisplayId is not null`, display the object's name (`video.Display.Name`).
2. Then load the whole list of `displays` into options with `foreach`, except the currently selected.
3. If `video.DisplayId is not null` then add an option at the end for `"None"`.

When loading the Blazor page, everything looks fine with its values, and when I select i.e. from `video.Display.Name` to `"None"`, and hit Save, it works.

But as soon as I go from `"None"` to a `display.Name`, it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object (see my code below, where it's saying it).

My code:

```
<InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="video.DisplayId">
    @if (video.DisplayId is null)
    {
        <option selected value="">None</option>
    }
    else 
    {
        // Object reference not set to an instance of an object ....
        <option selected value="@video.DisplayId">@video.Display.Name</option>
    }
    @foreach (Display display in displays.Where(display => display.Id != video.DisplayId))
    {
        <option value="@display.Id">@display.Name</option>
    }
    @if (video.DisplayId is not null)
    {
        <option value="">None</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```

I think it has something to do with Blazor and how it's rendering the page after I select, but how do I fix this issue?

Comment: If you select a value. Then it is filtered out of the list what do you want to display as the selected value of the `<InputSelect`?

Comment: The selected value `@video.Display.Name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many more hours, I figured it out. I needed to rewrite the code to following:

```
<InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="video.DisplayId">
    @if (video.DisplayId is null)
    {
        <option selected value="">None</option>
    }
    @foreach (Display display in displays)
    {
        <option value="@display.Id">@display.Name (ID: @display.Id)</option>
    }
    @if (video.DisplayId is not null)
    {
        <option value="">None</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```

And after pressing Save, it calls my method, and inside my method it's changing the data inside the database, and then after that I had to Get the list again from the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
@page "/"

<EditForm Model=@video>
    <InputSelect @bind-Value=@video.DisplayId>
        @if (video.DisplayId is null)
        {
            <option value="">none</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value=@selectedDisplay?.Id>@selectedDisplay?.Name</option>
        }
        @foreach (var display in unSelectedDisplays)
        {
            <option value=@display.Id>@display.Name</option>
        }
        @if (video.DisplayId is not null)
        {
            <option value="">none</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Video video = new Video();
    private IEnumerable<Display> displays = Enumerable.Empty<Display>();

    private IEnumerable<Display> unSelectedDisplays => 
        displays.Where(display => display.Id != video.DisplayId);

    Display? selectedDisplay => video.DisplayId.HasValue ?
                            displays.First(d => d.Id == this.video.DisplayId) :
                            default(Display);

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        displays = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
            .Select(i => new Display { Id = i, Name = $"Name{i}" });
    }

    public class Display
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Video
    {
        public int? DisplayId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code I have works fine, but when I try going from "None" to one of the foreach items, the Object reference not set to an instance of an object occurs. I think it's because I'm not getting the object (`video.Display`), only after I click 'Save' button where my call to my API happen and then changes the object. How would I go about this? I read somewhere about ValueChanged(() => AMethodToCall(?))? Or is there any way to make the InputSelect static until I click Save, if you understand?

Comment: Because with your code, I see the first <option> is null, whereas I want it to be whatever it is in the database.

Comment: @Zecret I changed it to put the selected item to the top and null at the bottom if not selected.

Comment: @Zecret I preload the list to 'Enumerable.Empty<Display>()'. If your async loading the displays you might want to put an `@if` block around the form untill all the resources are loaded for the select.

Comment: I don't have a `private Video video = new Video();`-field as you do as a model. I'm using a `@foreach (Video video in videos)` (where videos is full of videos from OnInitializedAsync), and using the `video` as a model. How do I use your code with my foreach video in videos?

Comment: @Zecret Break this into a subcomponent then with a parameter of type Video.

Comment: the `<option value="subcomponent(video)">...`?